# translate-x makes unwanted scroll

Tags: css

I have this html and try to apply animation with translate in css:

```
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="img_wave" />
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and css(I will attach sandbox code in follow):

```
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.background {
  width: 140%;
  height: 130%;
  background-image: url("/images/background.jpg");
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.bg_img {
  background-size: cover;
}
.img_wave {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300%;
  background-image: url("/images/Sea.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: wave 5s 0.1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translate3d(0, 10%, 0) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
```

and I want to hide this extra white spase on the right:
[image]

here is a code on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-colden-d8enr?file=/style.css:0-1361)
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is quite a lot of code in the sandbox. Could you extract just enough to show the problem and put your code direct into the question as a working snippet (use the <> icon when you edit the question) so we can try it for ourselves.

Comment: @AHaworth I tryed to use <> icon but I can not host my 2 images. On [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-colden-d8enr?file=/style.css:0-1361) just ```index.html``` and ‍‍‍```style.css``` belongs to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply these changes :

```
.img_wave {
  height: 450px;
  width: 120%;
  background-image: url("/images/Sea.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -50px;
  animation: wave 5s 0.1s infinite linear;
}
```